# How to change the array entries with order = 'F' in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to replace some entries of an array. I have to use the order='F' for compatibility reasons. The array I am working with is big, yet to reproduce the problem try the following.

This works:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]])

a.reshape((4, 1), order = 'C')[2] = 8

a = array([[1, 2],
           [8, 5]])
```

The following doesn't work:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]])

a.reshape((4, 1), order = 'F')[2] = 8

a = array([[1, 2],
           [4, 5]])
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: okay, I tried this and it seems to work.

    a = np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]]); 

    a2 = a.reshape((4, 1), order = 'F'); 

    a2[1] =8; 

    a = a2.reshape((2, 2), order = 'F');  

    a = array([[1, 2],
                    [8, 5]])

Comment: `reshape` tries to make a `view`, but may have to make a `copy`.  See its documented disclaimer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `'C'` type array this will get you a new 4x1 array that references all the same elements as the original array:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]])
a.reshape((4, 1), order = 'C')[2] = 8
```

So, the result is the same as doing this:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]])
b = a.reshape((4, 1), order = 'C')
b[2] = 8  # this line also changes a, because it references the same elements
print(a)
print(b)
```

Result:

```
[[1 2]
 [8 5]] 
[[1]
 [4]
 [8]
 [5]]
```

However, this doesn't work in the same way:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]])
a.reshape((4, 1), order = 'F')[2] = 8
```

Because `a.reshape((4, 1), order = 'F')` does give you a reshaped array, but it's an entirely new copy of the same array with different dimensions and thus changing it won't change the original array:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]])
b = a.reshape((4, 1), order = 'F')  # you get a copy, order 'F'
b[2] = 8  # this line does not change a, because it references different elements.
print(a)
print(b)
```

Result:

```
[[1 2]
 [4 5]] 
[[1]
 [4]
 [8]
 [5]]
```

However, if you define `a` as an `F` order array as well, `a` and `b` can share their data, but the result may be surprisingly different (this is the whole point of the different ordering):

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]], order = 'F')
b = a.reshape((4, 1), order = 'F')
b[2] = 8  # this line does change a, they share their data, both order 'F'.
print(a)
print(b)
```

Result:

```
[[1 8]
 [4 5]]
[[1]
 [4]
 [8]
 [5]]
```

Note the result as printed for `a`!

Answer (score 0):

`unravel_index` is another way of accessing a flat index in the `F` order:

```
In [120]: a[np.unravel_index(2, a.shape, order='C')]                                                         
Out[120]: 4
In [121]: a[np.unravel_index(2, a.shape, order='F')]                                                         
Out[121]: 2
In [122]: a.reshape((4,1),order='C')                                                                         
Out[122]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [4],      # <==
       [5]])
In [123]: a.reshape((4,1),order='F')                                                                         
Out[123]: 
array([[1],
       [4],
       [2],     # <==
       [5]])
```

Confirming that this allows us to set a value:

```
In [124]: a[np.unravel_index(2, a.shape, order='F')]=8                                                       
In [125]: a                                                                                                  
Out[125]: 
array([[1, 8],
       [4, 5]])
```

Comment: It's a useful bit of relevant information, thanks, but it skirts the actual problem that OP had, namely that their original data did not get modified when changing order. In your example, that's avoided by directly accessing the original with an appropriate index.